# Where to start .NET Entity Framework and ORM?

Tags: .net, entity, orm

I haven't used any database system enough but i believe i know  logic of databases and i have learnt little sql so i shouldn't start to learn ORM before learn them well?

Where can i start to learn .NET Entity Framework and which version of framework i have to start 3.5 or 4.0 because  i heard that 4.0 has strong support for Entity Framework.I am looking sources web pages,e-books or other else.

Comment: In my opinion just require to understand database concepts for start learn ORM.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the [official MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572(v=VS.100).aspx) has a lot of links to tutorial-style walkthroughs and videos. If you understand normalization, foreign keys, and the concept of Join tables, then you should be ready to start learning EF.

I recommend using EF4. It's what I would consider the first really mature (production-ready) version. Skip the stuff on "Entity SQL" - it's hardly ever needed. Just use LINQ to Entities instead.

There's one ebook that I've found useful, [Microsoft Entity Framework in Action](http://www.manning.com/mostarda/). It's not actually published yet, but the publisher (Manning) has a cool option where you can purchase the book now and read it in ebook draft form. A warning, though: the grammar is pretty bad, to the point of being distracting (because Manning's editors haven't fixed it all up yet).

There are a few good blogs as well, though they usually contain more technical content than MSDN (!). The [Entity Framework Design Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/efdesign/) describes the reasons behind the design decisions in EF. The [ADO.NET Team Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/) also has good content, though they also have content that doesn't deal with EF.

Comment: I always found blogs less usefull for starting.Subject doesn't goes step by step and they are like exist for person who already know it.Or i really don't know how to learn from blogs.Also i really don't get enough benefit from MSDN .MSDN is not good enough or i don't know how to use it effectively.E-books looks best then checking articles is good.

Comment: MSDN for EF has a more tutorial-style approach. Give it a try.